# can't set the 'confirmed' value to true when confirming the email with jwt and mongoose

Tags: mongoose, jwt, mongoose-schema, email-verification

I made this email confirmation: [sign the token when user is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5mAG.png)

```
   User.createUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(user);

          jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user.email,
              id: user._id
            },
            process.env.REG_SECRET,
            {
               expiresIn: "1h"
            },
            (err, emailToken) => {
              const url = `http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation/${emailToken}`
              const message = {
                text: ` <p>Please, click this link to confirm your email</p>
                  <a href=${url}> ${url} </a>`,
                subject: "Verification email"
              }
                 mailer.emailVerification(email, message);
            },
          );

          req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered! Verify your email to Login');
          res.redirect('/');
      });
```

I'm using the following mongoose model: [focus on the confirmed value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSQZy.png)

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
    },
  confirmed: {
     type: Boolean,
     defaultValue: false
   },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
    timestamps: {
      type: Boolean
    }
});
```

The user cant login if the value confirmed is set to false

```
  if (user.confirmed === true) {
            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
              } else  {
                  return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
                }
             });
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Please confirm your email to login'});
      }
```

when they click on the link with jwt in it, the value is supposed to turn from false to true but it doesn't since I still get the error when trying to log in " Email is not confirmed" [I tried different methods for it to work but it doesn't seem to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYE8w.png) Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
router.get('/confirmation/:token', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { user: { id } } = jwt.verify(req.params.token, REG_SECRET);
        await models.User.update({confirmed: true }, { where: { id } });

      } catch (e) {
        res.status('404');
      }

     const login = " Your email is verified!"
     return res.render('index', {login: login});
});
```

Comment: You need to post relevant code as formatted text as part of your question.

Comment: Hey Mary, every link you click is a picture with the code :)

Comment: No, SO requires relevant code to be part of the text of the question. Not external links. How are we to copy the code to test it? You are going to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. Yes?

Comment: yeah you right) done

Comment: Thank you, Tonnie and Welcome to Stack Overflow.